# Navegación en google maps

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con lo siguiente, tengo una app en android, en donde yo le paso una polyline o trazado y las paradas que debe hacer durante ese trazado, las muestro en un mapa de google y hasta ahi todo bien, el problema viene cuando yo intento hacer la navegación por voz, tengo un boton en mi app el cual me redirige a google maps pasandole yo mis paradas y pues sobre eso hace un trazado, me encontre con el porblema de que google maps solo acepta hasta 25 paradas, por lo tanto si el conjunto de mis paradas, tiene 26 paradas solo me permite hacer una navegación hasta la primer parada, pero me gustaria ver todas, ya que tengo rutas de hasta 48 paradas.

1 imagen: Esta es mi ruta con 25 paradas. 2 Imagen: Asi es como me lo muestra google maps. 3 imagen: Esta es mi ruta de 20 paradas. 4 imagen: Asi es como se deberia de ver google maps al pasarle todas las paradas.

[image: Esta es mi ruta con 25 paradas]
[image: Asi es como me lo muestra google maps]
[image: Esta es mi ruta de 20 paradas]
[image: Asi es como se deberia de ver google maps al pasarle todas las paradas]

---

Este es el codigo que utilizo

```
private fun startNavigation() {
        // Iniciar la navegación desde la posición actual hasta la última parada
        if (currentLocation != null && allMarkers.isNotEmpty()) {
            var listLatLng = mutableListOf<LatLng>()
            allMarkers.forEach{
                listLatLng.add(LatLng(it.position.latitude,it.position.longitude))
            }

        listLatLng = UtilDistance.findNearestNeighborOrder(listLatLng).toMutableList()

        val uriBuilder = StringBuilder("https://www.google.com/maps/dir/")

        // Añadir la ubicación actual como punto de inicio
        uriBuilder.append("${currentLocation!!.latitude},${currentLocation!!.longitude}/")

        for (position in listLatLng) {
            uriBuilder.append("${position.latitude},${position.longitude}/")
        }

        // Eliminar el último "/" de la URL
        uriBuilder.setLength(uriBuilder.length - 1)

        val uri = Uri.parse(uriBuilder.toString())
        val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")

        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(mapIntent)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps no está instalado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```